# Exception during creation of TopicSubscriber in Tibco EMS

Tags: java, tibco, tibco-ems

I'm using tibco ems and creating TopicSubscriber on particular topic and during subscriber creation I'm getting following exception.

```
Exception occured while creating object:EmailVerificationAsyncConsumerjavax.jms.**JMSSecurityException: Not permitted**
        at com.tibco.tibjms.Tibjmsx.buildException(Tibjmsx.java:591)
        at com.tibco.tibjms.TibjmsxSessionImp._createConsumer(TibjmsxSessionImp.java:448)
        at com.tibco.tibjms.TibjmsxSessionImp._createConsumer(TibjmsxSessionImp.java:370)
        at com.tibco.tibjms.TibjmsTopicSession.createSubscriber(TibjmsTopicSession.java:58)
        at com.sybase365.mobiliser.custom.project.jms.EmailVerificationAsyncConsumer.<init>(EmailVerificationAsyncConsumer.java:46)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method).
```

Please suggest the way to solve this problem.

Comment: Is the topic (and EMS instance) secured ? Did the JNDI connection string include username and password ?

Comment: Thanks Alex for considering my issue, Topic is secured and connection includes username and password.

Answer (score 1):

If `$sys.lookup` has `secure` property, you need to `grant` at least `send` permission to the user.

Connect to **EMS Administrator Tool** and run the below command to do the same:

`grant queue $sys.lookup <user_name> send`